# background-size is not working like it should

Tags: html, css, background, background-size

I recently changed monitors and now that I'm using a 1920x1080 resolution I've noticed that *`background-size`* property is malfunctioning on one of my sites (either that or I've misunderstood how it works for all this time).

The thing is, no matter if I set it to *`cover`* nor to *`100% 100%`*. It just will never cover the whole page height (and both html and body tags have min-height: 100vh. [I applied a blue background to the body just to check it had the proper size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvuX0.jpg)).

The website in question can be found [here](http://metaltxus.altervista.org/animelist).

```
body {
    background: url("../resources/images/bg.jpg") fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    color: $c-golden-darker;
    text-shadow: #1a0e0b 0 0 3px, #1a0e0b 0 0 3px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    min-height: 100vh;
    height: auto;
}
```

EDIT: After a second look, the image itself is a JPEG so it makes no sense for it to have transparent pixels.

EDIT2: Re-uploading the image to the server somehow fixed the problem.

Comment: Source code of your site will change but this question remains. So please add source codes to this question so that it may be helpful for others with same issue.

Comment: I agree with the earlier comment. You should always add the relevant code and/or create a MVCE. Coming to your problem, it seems like the image itself has the transparent area at the bottom. You need to crop it out.

Comment: It didn't occur to me but I agree.
Thanks for pointing out the problem as well. I'd choose yours as the best answer had you written it as one. Will do if you do.

Comment: Please include the relevant snippets in the question itself, don't link to an archive of the source code for the whole site.

Comment: Added css rules for the body to the main post, @Clive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's working fine, the problem is in your image which contain an empty space at the end of it.

[image]

as you see, I just inspect element and change your image with another and it work fine.

You can also can see the problem of your image here :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

your image has grey space in the bottom... 
The property background-size is working correctly.

Have a look here:
http://metaltxus.altervista.org/animelist/resources/images/bg.jpg